# How to install Notepad++ using bolt task

Tags: windows, powershell, puppet, puppet-bolt

To install `apache2`, we can use command similar to below

```
bolt task run package action=install name=apache2
```

I want to install `Notepad++` in windows machine using `bolt task`.

Is there any `Notepad++` package similar to below to install using `bolt task`.

```
bolt task run package action=install name=notepad++
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chocolatey, the package name ([for the community repo](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=notepad%2B%2B)) is `notepadplusplus`.

So your command would be:

```
bolt task run package name=notepadplusplus action=install
```

If you're not using chocolatey in your windows environment, then you'll need to find a different way to do this.

Comment: I'm not using chocolatey . Could you please sugges anyt other ways.

Comment: If you aren't using chocolatey, you'll need to write a task to install it however your company installs software. That might mean mounting up a network share, installing an msi, and then unmounting. I can't really tell you what to do without knowing what your company uses. But, chocolatey is the only package installer supported by the package task, and it's actually pretty annoying to manage a Windows puppet environment without chocolatey, so I'd suggest looking into it.